# Вы в программу вводите данные об игроках и она их сравнивает. Как вывести max+ и фамилию игрока

Tags: c++, c, массивы

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct PlayerInfo
{
    string surname;
    string command;
    string position;
    int kol_zabityh_myachey;
    int kol_peredach;
    int kol_tochnyh_peredach;
    float distance;
};



int main()
{
    int n, max;
    max = 0;
    cout << "kolplaeers" << '\n';
    cin >> n;
    PlayerInfo players[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "surname: " << i << '\n';
        cin >> players[ i ].surname;
        cout << "command " << players[ i ].surname << '\n';
        cin >> players[ i ].command;
        cout << "position " << players[ i ].surname << '\n';
        cin >> players[ i ].position;
        cout << "kol_zabityh_myachey " << players[ i ].surname << '\n';
        cin >> players[ i ].kol_zabityh_myachey;
        cout << "kol_peredach " << players[ i ].surname << '\n';
        cin >> players[ i ].kol_peredach;
        cout << "kol_tochnyh_peredach " << players[ i ].surname << '\n';
        cin >> players[ i ].kol_tochnyh_peredach;
        cout << "distance " << players[ i ].surname << '\n';
        cin >> players[ i ].distance;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (players[ i ].kol_peredach - players[ i ].kol_tochnyh_peredach >
                max)
            max = players[ i ].kol_peredach - players[ i ].kol_tochnyh_peredach;
    }

    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Максимум чего вы ищите?

Answer (score 1):

```
int maxidx = -1;

...

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   if(players[ i ].kol_peredach-players[ i ].kol_tochnyh_peredach > max) 
   {    
       max=players[ i ].kol_peredach-players[ i ].kol_tochnyh_peredach; 
       maxidx = i;
   }
} 

cout << max << "  Name: " << players[maxidx].surname << "\n";
```

Так сойдет?